# Porque nohup não aceita for loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script

Eu tenho esse codigo dentro de um arquivo chamado teste.sh
Quando tento executar

```
nohup ./teste.sh &
```

ele dá esse erro. Alguém sabe me explicar ?

> ./teste.sh: 9: ./teste.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

CODIGO

```
cuda="cuda.out";
cpu="cpu.out";
cudaTxt="cuda.out.txt";
cpuTxt="cpu.out.txt";
trash="/dev/null";
rm -f $cudaTxt;
rm -f $cpuTxt;
```

for ((i=10001;i<=1000001;i+=10000));
do
    echo "Cuda, $i iteração";
    head -n$i formulas.txt > formulas_pre-processadas_CUSTOMIZADA.txt;
    echo -en "$i\t" >> $cudaTxt;
    ./$cuda | cut -c19- >> $cudaTxt;
done;

for ((i=10001;i<=1000001;i+=10000));
do
    echo "CPU, $i iteração";
    head -n$i formulas.txt > formulas_pre-processadas_CUSTOMIZADA.txt;
    echo -en "$i\t" >> $cpuTxt;
    ./$cpu | cut -c19- >> $cpuTxt;
done;

echo "Acabou";

Comment: Qual shell vc ta usando?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 , shell normal dele, não sei se isso responde sua pergunta ...

Comment: Vc tentou rodar sem o `nohup` para ver se ele é o problema mesmo? E para saber qual shell vc está usando, rode `echo $SHELL` ou `echo $0` e veja qual é a saída. Alguns shells possuem sintaxes ligeiramente diferentes e nem sempre o script vai funcionar igual em todos. Uma dica é colocar na primeira linha do script o shell que vc quer usar para rodá-lo (por exemplo: `#!/bin/bash` para usar o bash: http://e-tinet.com/linux/programacao-shell-script/ )

Comment: Sim, tentei e rodou.

"echo $SHELL -> /bin/bash"
'echo $0 -> -bash"

Comment: @hkotsubo
Coloquei o #!/bin/bash e funcionou
Mas por quê ?

Comment: @Tequelequeteque Creio que os comentários na resposta do Marcelo abaixo esclarecem à sua dúvida. Quando vc roda o comando direto (sem nohup), o bash roda o script (já que o shell que vc está usando é o bash). Mas quando vc roda com nohup, ele usa algum outro shell que não o bash (e este outro shell não reconhece esta sintaxe do `for`). Mas colocando `#!/bin/bash` no início do script, vc diz que ele deve ser sempre executado pelo bash, e aí funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque o `for ((i = 10001; i <= 1000001; i += 10000));` por

```
i = 1
while [ $((i += 10000)) -le 1000001 ]
do
    ...
done;
```

EDIT: este formato de laço for que você usou não é suportado por todos os tipos de shell, especialmente aqueles que não suportam POSIX. O bash é um deles. Por isso que a mensagem de erro continha "Bad for loop variable".

Comment: se possível explique a sua solução

Comment: Eu tentei, funcionou mas tbm não entendi...

Comment: Mas eu usei sem o nohup e funcionou normalmente... eu não estou entendo porque do erro... quando uso `./teste.sh &` ele funciona e quando uso `nohup ./teste.sh &` ele dá esse erro ... Pelo que eu entendi do erro foi que o esse formato de for loop que eu usei é entendida pelo BASH mas por algum motivo quando uso com o nohup ele não entende...

Comment: Quando você tá num `nohup`, o run level é outro e pode ser que nesse run level, o shell seja outro.

Comment: Eu coloquei #!/bin/bash e funcionou tbm, deve ser exatamente o que você falou, Obrigado :D

Comment: @MarceloUchimura A sua resposta está correta quanto ao método POSIX de implementar tal aritmética (faz a soma dentro de um `test` como parâmetro para um `while`), mas acho que há uma pequena confusão na explicação: É O POSIX que não suporta loops `for` com definição em blocos aritméticos `(( ... ))`. O `sh` falha com um loop desses, o `bash` não. Este documento esclarece bastante coisa: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2039#arithmetic-for-loops